# passing parameters into SQL server - "must declare scalar variable"

Tags: sql-server, scalar

EDIT:

In an effort to clean up the SQL just a little, I've written the code as PeterHE suggested, and hardcoded in (just for testing) the test values.  Now I'm getting a new error message:  "in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_CategoryID_fk" could not be bound."

Here's the revised test code:

```
    select in_eq_ID, in_eq_TagNumber as TagNumber, Title1Item, in_eq_AssetDescription as Description, in_eq_ExtendedDescription as ExtendedDescription, in_eq_SerialNumber as SerialNumber, in_eq_ValuationAmount as TotalValue, in_eq_CustodianName as Name, in_eq_ComplexBuilding as ShortLocation, in_eq_SubLocationCode as ShortRoomNumber, in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryName as CategoryName, in_eq_DispositionDate as DispositionDate, Departments.DepartmentCode, DATEADD (dd, 0, DATEDIFF (dd, 0, in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_AcquisitionDate)) as AcquisitionDate

from in_eq_Equipment, Departments

LEFT JOIN in_ca_Categories ON in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_CategoryID_fk = in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryID       
where in_eq_Equipment.DepartmentID = CAST ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS nvarchar(36)) and upper (in_eq_AssetDescription) LIKE upper ('%T$')
```

---

Rusty old programmer here returning... trying to test a stored procedure and running into this error message.  Error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 18 
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@DepartmentID".

// The test calling code:

```
DECLARE @SearchString varchar(30), @DispositionText varchar(200)
declare @DepartmentID uniqueidentifier;

SET @SearchString = 'T'
SET @DispositionText = '';
SET @DepartmentID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
EXEC GetInventoryByAssetDescription @SearchString, @DispositionText, @DepartmentID
```

Actual stored procedure code (Yes, I know it's bad code--I didn't write it originally, but must modify it within a short timeframe):

```
USE [Inventory]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]    Script Date: 12/23/2019 9:09:51 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]
      (
            @SearchString varchar(30),
            @DispositionText varchar(200) = null,
            @DepartmentID uniqueidentifier
      )  
AS
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @sql nvarchar (2000)

    select @SearchString=UPPER(@SearchString)
    set @sql = '   select in_eq_ID,
        in_eq_TagNumber as TagNumber,
        Title1Item,
        in_eq_AssetDescription as Description,
        in_eq_ExtendedDescription as ExtendedDescription,
        in_eq_SerialNumber as SerialNumber,
        in_eq_ValuationAmount as TotalValue,
        in_eq_CustodianName as Name,
        in_eq_ComplexBuilding as ShortLocation,
        in_eq_SubLocationCode as ShortRoomNumber,
        in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryName as CategoryName,
        in_eq_DispositionDate as DispositionDate,
        Departments.DepartmentCode,
        DATEADD (dd, 0, DATEDIFF (dd, 0, in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_AcquisitionDate)) as AcquisitionDate
        from in_eq_Equipment, Departments
        where in_eq_Equipment.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID
            LEFT JOIN in_ca_Categories ON in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_CategoryID_fk = in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryID
            WHERE upper (in_eq_AssetDescription) LIKE upper ('''+ @SearchString + ''')
            '


        set  @sql=@sql+'   ' + ISNULL(@DispositionText,' ')  + '  order by in_eq_AssetDescription'
        execute (@sql)
        return
end
```

Comment: Yes it is bad. Not just bad - terrible. There are lots of problems with it. Duplicate upper logic, old style joins, what appears to be a faulty join between equipment and departments, dispositiontext can easily cause an error. And most importantly - susceptible to SQL INJECTION.

Comment: If you are allowed to modify the stored proc, why are you using dynamic SQL because it performs poor. There is nothing in your SQL SELECT that needs to dynamic parameters. All are straight forward, taking just from inputs. I would say, just remove that dynamic sql logic, have a normal SQL SELECT statement which just queries your respective tables based on input parameters.

Comment: This original SQL was apparently created in 2005.  I am so rusty and under a timeline, doubt I have time to clean it up completely.  Just trying to make a minor modification at this point.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: What you have doesn't make sense. What is `@DispositionText`? You just inject it into your statement, which makes no sense. Why are you cross joining to `departments`? Shouldn't it be an `INNER JOIN` and then `@DepartmentID` is compared against the column in the `departments` table? Why do you have 2 `WHERE` clauses as well?

Comment: *"This original SQL was apparently created in 2005"* and would never have worked in 2005. `FROM TAble1, Table2 WHERE Table1.Col = 1 LEFT JOIN Table3 ON...` is complete wrong syntax.

Comment: It worked in 2005.  That may be the result of multiple programmers monkeying around with the code for the last 14 years.

Comment: I'm going to try to clean it up a bit.  I also agree it is a bit incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

The where clause:

```
where in_eq_Equipment.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID
```

Should be:

```
where in_eq_Equipment.DepartmentID = '''+CAST(@DepartmentID AS nvarchar(36))+'''
```

P.S.:
It does not look like you need dynamic sql at all. Also even if you need, should change to use sp_executesql with parameters.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, it should be a parameter. This leaves the SP wide open to injection. This answer is **dangerous** because it doesn't address the problem, and actually further endorses injection..

Comment: But Peter's suggestion does correct OP's error. It is not the best solution but it works.

Comment: It does "work", yes @SMor , just like a `WHILE` works for inserting many rows from one table to another, or using adhesive tap to fix a leaking pipe. Doesn't mean you should do it though.

Comment: Yes, but you should actually show that, @PeterHe . Especially as the SQL isn't dynamic at all; there is literally no need for the injection, and therefore huge security vulnerability.

Comment: @Larnu, NO. He needs to try that. The answer gives the solution.

Comment: Thanks, PeterHe.  Replacing that line of code leaves me with this error, however:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

Comment: You need to move your join before the WHERE clause

Comment: It gives a bad solution, and that's the real problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQLs are very bad. I am just giving the code which prevents the errors that you are seeing:

```
USE [Inventory]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]    Script Date: 12/23/2019 9:09:51 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]
      (
            @SearchString varchar(30),
            @DispositionText varchar(200) = null,
            @DepartmentID uniqueidentifier
      )  
AS
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @sql nvarchar (2000)

select @SearchString=UPPER(@SearchString)
set @sql = '   select in_eq_ID,
    in_eq_TagNumber as TagNumber,
    Title1Item,
    in_eq_AssetDescription as Description,
    in_eq_ExtendedDescription as ExtendedDescription,
    in_eq_SerialNumber as SerialNumber,
    in_eq_ValuationAmount as TotalValue,
    in_eq_CustodianName as Name,
    in_eq_ComplexBuilding as ShortLocation,
    in_eq_SubLocationCode as ShortRoomNumber,
    in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryName as CategoryName,
    in_eq_DispositionDate as DispositionDate,
    Departments.DepartmentCode,
    DATEADD (dd, 0, DATEDIFF (dd, 0, in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_AcquisitionDate)) as AcquisitionDate
    from in_eq_Equipment, Departments
        LEFT JOIN in_ca_Categories ON in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_CategoryID_fk = in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryID
        WHERE 
           in_eq_Equipment.DepartmentID = '''+CAST(@DepartmentID AS nvarchar(36))+'''
           upper (in_eq_AssetDescription) LIKE upper ('''+ @SearchString + ''')' --searchString is already converted UPPER CASE at the beginning, not sure why its converted here again.

    set  @sql=@sql+'   ' + ISNULL(@DispositionText,' ')  + '  order by in_eq_AssetDescription'
    execute (@sql)
    return
```

end

And below is the refactored stored procedure which directly takes your SQL inputs and returns the resultset:

```
USE [Inventory]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]
      (
            @SearchString varchar(30),
            @DispositionText varchar(200) = null,
            @DepartmentID uniqueidentifier
      )  
AS
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @SearchString = '''%' + UPPER('test') + ''''
select in_eq_ID
       , in_eq_TagNumber as TagNumber
       , Title1Item
       , in_eq_AssetDescription as [Description]
       , in_eq_ExtendedDescription as ExtendedDescription
       , in_eq_SerialNumber as SerialNumber
       , in_eq_ValuationAmount as TotalValue
       , in_eq_CustodianName as [Name]
       , in_eq_ComplexBuilding as ShortLocation
       , in_eq_SubLocationCode as ShortRoomNumber
       , in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryName as CategoryName
       , in_eq_DispositionDate as DispositionDate
       , Departments.DepartmentCode
       , DATEADD (dd, 0, DATEDIFF (dd, 0, in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_AcquisitionDate)) as AcquisitionDate
from      in_eq_Equipment
JOIN      Departments      ON in_eq_equipment.departmentid = departments.id
LEFT JOIN in_ca_Categories ON in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_CategoryID_fk = in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryID       
where (in_eq_Equipment.DepartmentID =  @DepartmentID OR @DepartmentID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') 
     and upper (in_eq_AssetDescription) LIKE @SearchString 
     --AND ISNULL(@DispositionText,' ') = ' '  -- Not able to understand this condition from your dynamic SQL
order by in_eq_AssetDescription  
        return
end
```

Comment: I'm actually in the middle of refactoring the code, but your second code slice is getting the same error I am:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetInventoryByAssetDescription, Line 33
The multi-part identifier "in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_CategoryID_fk" could not be bound.

Comment: @Brian My second code slice just replaces the same query from your POST with direct SQL instead of dynamic SQL. That error means, in_eq_CategoryID_fk column is not found in in_eq_Equipment table. Without knowing your tables structures, its hard to fix that error.

Comment: Thanks, Sam... but in_eq_CategoryID_fk actually IS in the in_eq_Equipment table.  That's what causing my confusion.

Comment: How are in_eq_Equipment, Departments joined?

Comment: in_eq_equipment.departmentid = departments.id      

I am rewriting the SP now... going to take a bit because I am so rusty. :(

Comment: Updated my second slice of code with the join that you have shared here. Please try when you get a chance and post your observations after you are done with your re-write.

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  No errors now, but getting no results.  Taking a look now at my data and seeing what might be wrong.

Comment: Could you comment this line and upper (in_eq_AssetDescription) LIKE @SearchString and see if that return any data? If you are getting data back after commenting this condition, then your next focus area is fixing this condition.

Comment: I have that fixed now.  Silly mistake on my part.  Not sure how to handle a couple of things, like Disposition SQL text that is passed in and how to handle "ALL" Departments, which is a "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Guid.  But otherwise, it's compiling and mostly running at this point.  Thanks, Sam!

Comment: I have updated my second query to include this condition (in_eq_Equipment.DepartmentID =  @ DepartmentID OR @ DepartmentID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'). Please use that and post your observations on whether it suits your requirement or not